# Recursion error when accessing an array attribute that is defined from class level

Tags: python

So here is my code, i'm tying to make a simple node tree:

```
class Node(object):
    child = []
    def __init__(self,id):
            self.id =id
    def addChild(self,child):
            self.child.append(child)
    def printChildOnwards(self):
            yield self.id
            for x in self.child:
                    yield from x.printChildOnwards()


firstChild = Node('1')
secondChild = Node('2')
thirdChild = Node('3')
fourthChild = Node('4')

firstChild.addChild(secondChild)
firstChild.addChild(thirdChild)


for x in firstChild.printChildOnwards():
    print(x)
```

I have accessed the defined class level attribute through `self` to make sure that I am accessing its own version.

Output:
`1 2 2 2 2 ... then recursion error max depth`

Although it works if I will simply define it inside the `__init__` like this 
`self.child = []`

Output: `1 2 3`

What is the reason behind this behavior? why do I need to include it in `__init__` ?

Comment: Side-note: Since you're on Python 3 (`yield from` gives it away), it's not necessary to explicitly inherit from `object`. That's only necessary in Python 2 (to force new-style class behavior), but in Python 3, all classes are "new-style" and implicitly inherit from `object`.

Comment: Oh alright thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In your initial example:

```
class Node(object):

    child = []

    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id
```

The `child` attribute is a class level attribute on the `Node` class, which means every single instances of `Node` will share that object, thus every iteration through the `printChildOnwards` call will simply keep printing from this same list.  As you found, defining it at the `__init__` method works, as that creates an instance level `child` attribute for each instance, thus they are now all unique and won't result in iterating through the same shared list of children.

You can easily verify the identity (the memory address) of any object using the [`id`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#id) function.  With that you can see for yourself that the child attribute using this example is identical:

```
>>> n1 = Node(1)
>>> n2 = Node(2)
>>> id(n1.child)
139928077828744
>>> id(n2.child)
139928077828744
```

Changing it around back to the version you fixed:

```
class Node(object):             
    def __init__(self, id):     
        self.child = []              
        self.id = id
```

Verify again using the [`id`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#id) function once more and see that they are different.

```
>>> n1 = Node(1)                                               
>>> n2 = Node(2)                                                               
>>> id(n1.child)
139928077829192
>>> id(n2.child)
139928077828936
```

Comment: So that means that class level attributes must be defined first at the init to make them unique to each other?

Comment: Yes.  I just updated the answer to better demonstrate this.

Comment: @CarlosMiguelColanta: Not exactly, it means you that you shouldn't use _class_ attributes for _instance_ state. Class attributes are shared among all instances, so the first time any instance appends to the shared list of children, all instances view that `Node` as their child, and now you've got infinite loops the first time you do a recursive loop over all children (because the first child you iterate will think it is its own child and iterate itself, which will iterate itself, and so on).